# Not able to overlap one div over another with z-index

Tags: html, css, z-index

I want to get my `.dynamic-tooltip` to overlay on my `.static-tooltip`. And my static tooltip has to be hidden.

But I am unable to do so with `z-index`. Please tell me where am I going wrong.

Please have a look at my code.
https://jsfiddle.net/x883m3hg/

```
<div class = "static-tooltip">
  <div class = "tooltip-container">
    <div class = "item-key">
    Static tooltip Key
    </div>
    <div class = "item-value">
    Static tooltip Value
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class = "dynamic-tooltip">
  <div class = "tooltip-container">
    <div class = "item-key">
    Dynamic tooltip Key
    </div>
    <div class = "item-value">
    Dynamic tooltip value
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.static-tooltip{
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
  width:100%;
  height: 30px;
}

.dynamic-tooltip{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:2;
  top:3px;
  width: 100%;
  height:30px
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `body` element has a default margin of 8px. Start by removing that:

```
body { margin: 0; }
```

Then reset the `top` offset on the `dynamic-tooltip` to `0`.

```
.dynamic-tooltip { top: 0; }
```

Here's your revised code:

- *added background colors for illustration*
- *no changes to HTML*
- *two changes to CSS*

```css
body {
  margin: 0;   /* new */
}
.static-tooltip {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: aqua;
}
.dynamic-tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0px;  /* adjusted */
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="static-tooltip">
  <div class="tooltip-container">
    <div class="item-key">
      Static tooltip Key
    </div>
    <div class="item-value">
      Static tooltip Value
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dynamic-tooltip">
  <div class="tooltip-container">
    <div class="item-key">
      Dynamic tooltip Key
    </div>
    <div class="item-value">
      Dynamic tooltip value
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Revised Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/x883m3hg/7/)

Answer (score 1):

The absolute positioned div must be within the relative one so as to overlap.

Edited code :

```css
.static-tooltip {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}
.dynamic-tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="static-tooltip">
  <div class="tooltip-container">
    <div class="item-key">
      Static tooltip Key
    </div>
    <div class="item-value">
      Static tooltip Value
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="dynamic-tooltip">
    <div class="tooltip-container">
      <div class="item-key">
        Dynamic tooltip Key
      </div>
      <div class="item-value">
        Dynamic tooltip value
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```